# Puzzled UserControl OnPaint with scroll bars

Tags: c#, windows, user-controls

I have some difficulty using scroll bars with a subclass of UserControl. I have used DrawTools 2005 (from CodeProject) to render medium sized graphs (500 edges). I added to it the possibility to scroll with H/V bars. Now what I can see is that using the Horizontal Scroll Bar the drawing is garbled as shown in the screen capture.

My question is: How to implement drawing in a UserControl , control that uses ScollBars ?

Link for the DrawTool 2005 utility:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8494/DrawTools

To see what the garbling look like see the following picture
http://arnault-bonafos.123siteweb.fr/311699731

The code for drawing look like the following:

```
private void CanvasArea_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.AutoScrollPosition.X, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y);

    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));//Color.FromArgb(127, 127, 127)); //Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush,
        this.ClientRectangle);

    if (canvasDocument != null)
    {
        canvasDocument.Draw(e.Graphics);
    }
    brush.Dispose();
}
```

As a note I tried both with or without `TranslateTransform`, but it leads to other bug, as shown in the picture in the previous link.

I wonder if `UserControl.Paint` method is thread safe or not ?

Could someone shed a light on this ?

Comment: Using TranslateTransform() is required.  There's some hint that you pinvoke FrameRgn(), it is not aware of the Graphics object state.  You'll have to offset the region yourself.  Do favor Graphics.DrawPath() instead.

Comment: Ok. I use Region because the code used CreateRoundRectRgn GDI function, this region was framed as you guessed right. How can I go from CreateRoundRectRgn to Graphics Path ?

Comment: Just use GraphicsPath.AddArc and AddLine.  8 lines of code should not slow you down.

Comment: Thanks it works. now I just have to fix the scroll bar issue, it is just that hte case is not supported in DrawTool 2005. I'll publish back to the community if I find a place.

Answer (score 0):

As guessed by Hans Passant, FrameRgn is not impacted by Graphics.TranslateTransform. it needs to be rewritten.
I needed the same functionality as CreateRoundRectRgn here is the code below that provide the same functionality.

```
    public static GraphicsPath GetRoundedRectangle(Rectangle rect, int rad)
    {
        int d = 2 * rad;
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gp =
                new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();

        gp.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y, d, d, 180, 90);
        gp.AddArc(rect.X + rect.Width - d, rect.Y, d, d, 270, 90);
        gp.AddArc(rect.X + rect.Width - d, rect.Y + rect.Height - d, d, d, 0, 90);
        gp.AddArc(rect.X, rect.Y + rect.Height - d, d, d, 90, 90);

        return gp;
    }
```

Having this, one can simply call Graphics.DrawPath(gp);

Again thanks for the help.